# Error filtering template: Invalid block type

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, widget, local

I'm trying to create my own widget in Magento 2 however I get this error:

> Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Inchoo1\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList

My code is identical to that of "https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-widget/".

Inchoo/CatalogWidget/Block/Product - ProductList.php

```
<?php
namespace Inchoo\CatalogWidget\Block\Product;

class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{
const DEFAULT_COLLECTION_SORT_BY = 'name';
const DEFAULT_COLLECTION_ORDER = 'asc';

public function createCollection()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
        ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getData('page_var_name'), 1))
        ->setOrder($this->getSortBy(), $this->getSortOrder());

    $conditions = $this->getConditions();
    $conditions->collectValidatedAttributes($collection);
    $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($collection, $conditions);

    return $collection;
}

public function getSortBy()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('collection_sort_by')) {
        $this->setData('collection_sort_by', self::DEFAULT_COLLECTION_SORT_BY);
    }
    return $this->getData('collection_sort_by');
}

public function getSortOrder()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('collection_sort_order')) {
        $this->setData('collection_sort_order', self::DEFAULT_COLLECTION_ORDER);
    }
    return $this->getData('collection_sort_order');
}
}
```

Can anyone please direct me towards a fix, thanks :)

Comment: I think you are using Inchoo1 extension or you have rename the Inchoo extension to Inchoo1. Remove that completely and then run setup upgrade, di compile and static content deploy.

Comment: It is named Inchoo1 everywhere as i already had another module called Inchoo. I don't know if i'm using the extension. All i did was follow this tutorial and change inchoo to inchoo1 - https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-widget/

Comment: Inchoo is a namespace, so it will not create any issue. You can put your module custom widget under the same Inchoo folder.

Comment: Okay, now I get the same error but with Inchoo not inchoo 1 - Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Inchoo\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList

Comment: Did you run setup upgrade, di compile and static-content deploy?

Comment: yes but still nothing

Comment: Did you find fix for this getting same error